# Entity Framework Core Include/ThenInclude to get the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have tables in my database with the following one-to-many relations:

```
a -> b
b -> c
b -> d
```

which are mapped to corresponding navigational properties in the model.

I want to get data from "a" with all related data from "b, c, d".

If I try:

```
dbcontext.a.Include(x => x.b)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.c)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.d)
```

I get an error because this implies a relationship `c -> d` (instead of `b -> d`).

Then, if I try:

```
dbcontext.a.Include(x => x.b)
           .ThenInclude(x => x.c)
           .Include(x => x.d)
```

I get an error because this implies a relationship `a -> d` (instead of `b -> d`).

I'd appreciate help on how to correctly chain the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you use net5

```
dbcontext.a.Include(x => x.b)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.c)
             .Include(x => x.b)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.d)
```

Or to avoid repeating  you can try ( was tested by @Marko )

```
dbcontext.a.Include(x => x.b)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.c)
             .Include(x => x.b.d)
```

but I prefer to use this syntax (fits for all versions)

```
dbcontext.a.Include(x => x.b)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.c)
             .Include("b.d")
```

Comment: Isn't it a little bit strange to include x.b twice (as in the first example)?

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you. This is why I use strings.

Comment: One expert advised me to use " .Include(x => x.b.d) " but I am not sure that it works. Pls try and let me know.

Comment: Do you mean .Include(x => x.b.d)?